# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make()

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am trying to migrate my Web Application from Weblogic to Jboss EAP 7.4. During the deployment I am getting following error.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make()Lorg/hibernate/validator/internal/util/logging/Log; \

War file has all the Hibernate specific libraries - WEB-INF/lib location.
I have tried to exclude Jboss specific library but not working
WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
     <exclusions>
     <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
     </exclusions>
     </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Are you including Hibernate in your deployment?

Comment: I encountered the same when deploying war to embedded Glassfish 5